# how to set telerik grid coumn width as fit to its headertext?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I am using telerik grid. Column header text will be retrived from stored procedure and i handled this all in code behind. I wanted to display the column header in single line, when there is no headertext available then it will display as "-1", "-2" like that.

I am trying is to auto fit the headertext in the column, the problem is while fixing column width using " HeaderStyle-Width="119px" " it is fine for datetime value but for -1 and -2 it occupies space.

Advice me to autoset column width according to the headertext.

[image]
I have place the grid definition below..

```
enter code here<cc1:logicaGrid 
    AutoSetColumnWidth="false" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="true"
    AllowPostBackOnRowClick="false" 
    AllowFilteringByColumn="false"
    BorderWidth="1"
    PageSize="100"
    Width="99%" 
    ID="grdProfiles" 
    AlwaysShowPager="true"      
    AllowPaging="true"
    runat="server" HeaderStyle-Width="119px">
    <MasterTableView Width = "100%"></MasterTableView>
    <ClientSettings 
        Scrolling-ScrollHeight="450px" 
        Scrolling-AllowScroll ="true" >
        <Resizing AllowColumnResize="true"/>
    </ClientSettings>
</cc1:logicaGrid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `HeaderStyle-Width="100%"`?

Comment: I have already tried this one.. Its displaying only 1st column.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: reason being if you have radGrid 100% will not display more columns

```
HeaderStyle-Width="100px"
```

Answer (score 0):

For each column you need to set HeaderStyle.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="ViewLogsGrid" 
 AutoGenerateColumns="false" ... ... >

   <MasterTableView TableLayout="Fixed">
      <Columns>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Comments" HeaderText="Comments" SortExpression="Comments"    UniqueName="Comments">

           <HeaderStyle Width="150px" />

        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
      </Columns>
   </MasterTableView>

</telerik:RadGrid>
```